# Struct in struct embedding promoted methods question

Tags: go, struct, embedding

```
package main

import "fmt"

type type1 struct { //T
}

func (t1 type1) type1Meth1() {
    fmt.Printf("==> func (t1 type1) type1Meth1():\n Type: %T\n Value: %+v\n\n", t1, t1)
}

func (t1 *type1) type1Meth2() {
    fmt.Printf("==> func (t1 *type1) type1Meth2():\n Type: %T\n Value: %p\n Contains: %+v\n\n", t1, t1, t1)
}

func (t1 type1) type1Meth3() {
    fmt.Printf("==> func (t1 type1) type1Meth3():\n Type: %T\n Value: %+v\n", t1, t1)
}

type type2 struct { //S
    type1
}

func (t2 *type2) type1Meth3() {
    fmt.Printf("==> func (t2 *type2) type1Meth3(): Type: %T\n Value: %+v\n\n", t2, t2)
}
func main() {
    t2 := type2{}
    t2.type1Meth1() // type2 contains method set of type1
    t2.type1Meth2() // not sure, why this works? type2 does not have method set of *type1 (A)
    t2.type1Meth3() // type2 contains method set of type1. intercepted by embedding type type2 and called with *type2 receiver
}
```

Gives me:

```
$ go run embed-struct-in-struct.go
==> func (t1 type1) type1Meth1():
 Type: main.type1
 Value: {}

==> func (t1 *type1) type1Meth2():
 Type: *main.type1
 Value: 0x116be80
 Contains: &{}

==> func (t2 *type2) type1Meth3(): Type: *main.type2
 Value: &{type1:{}}

go version
go version go1.17.2 darwin/amd64
```

Not sure why call in (A) works?
Documentation says: [promoted methods are included in the method set of the struct as follows:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> Given a struct type S and a defined type T, promoted methods are included in the method set of the struct as follows:

> If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
> If S contains an embedded field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T or *T.

Answer (score 3):

(A) works because the method call implicitly takes the address of the receiver.

The method `(*type1).type1Meth2()` is promoted to `*type2` per the promotion rules quoted in the question.

The  [section of the specification on calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) says:

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m():

The expression `t2.type1Meth2()` is shorthand for `(&t2).type1Meth2()` because `t2` is addressable and `type1Meth2()` is in the method set of `*type2`.

Comment: wow interesting. The rules for method sets inclusion are not straightforward.